# Set aspectRatio of the main window on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit

I need to make main window to preserve width/height ratio when the user resizes it on MacOS.

My first idea was to handle the following notification:

```
@interface Override_iOS : NSObject
@end

__strong Override_iOS *_instance;
@implementation Override_iOS
+(void)load
{
    NSLog(@"[Override_iOS load]");
    _instance = [Override_iOS new];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:_instance
                                            selector:@selector(applicationDidFinishLaunching:)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
                                            object:nil];
}
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"[Override_iOS applicationDidFinishLaunching:%@]", notification);
    //qDebug() << "applicationDidFinishLaunching handler";
}
@end
```

and try to set something like `aspectRatio` property of the main window, but looks like that this code would not work on MacOS, but only on iOS (at least in my app).

Is it possible to do something like this on MacOS?

Is there an option in XCode project?

**EDIT1**

I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291157/resize-cocoa-windows-proportionally):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Keep the aspect ratio constant at its current value
    [window setAspectRatio:window.frame.size];
}
```

but it is not clear where to add this.

**EDIT1**

Created a test app:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific aspect ratio you want used? Such as `3:2`? Or... your **EDIT1** says: *"// Keep the aspect ratio constant at its current value"* ... do you mean whatever aspect ration the user sized it to on the first run?

Comment: @DonMag constant ratio: 320 : 640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done very little with MacOS apps, but this may be what you're looking for...

Create a `NSWindow` subclass:

**MyWindowController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**MyWindowController.m**

```
#import "MyWindowController.h"

@interface MyWindowController ()
@end

@implementation MyWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    // set the aspect ratio here
    [self.window setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(320.0, 640.0)];
}

@end
```

Then assign the custom class of your window controller:

[image]

Comment: What type of project should I create to reproduce this in XCode? (I was able to compile you source code, but I do not see Window Controller in my app) added

Comment: Added my test app screenshot, see EDIT1

Comment: In fact is that in my real-life app I do not have XCode project at all, but CMake. And XCode project that CMake generates does not have some Window or Window Controller.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - your post was about Objective-C ... are you using SwiftUI ?

Comment: No, I am using QT (some cross-platform framework) that does not have Main Window Controller, so I am trying to create a project in Objective-C where I will be able to try your code.